# Rails 4 - how to write a helper method to present attribute names

Tags: ruby-on-rails, helper, presenter

I have a roles table with an attribute :name in it.

I'm trying to use a list of role names in a collection select.  Instead of listing the :name in the way it is recorded in the database, I want to present it neatly.

For example, :name has an instance stored as :admin in the database. I want to present that in the collection select as 'Administrator'.

I tried to write a roles helper that says:

module RolesHelper

```
def text_for_role(name)
  case name
      when 'guest'
        'Guest - Trial Account'
      when 'admin'
        'Administrator'
      when 'representative'
        'Representative'
         etc, etc
```

but this option isn't going to work in this context, because I want to list all the roles, but refer to them written nicely.

I have this collection select:

```
<%= select_tag "roles", options_from_collection_for_select(@roles, "id", "<%= text_for_role(name)%>"), :multiple => true, :class => 'chosen-select form-control' %>
```

Can anyone see how I can write a helper or a presenter that can be used on the whole list of collection select options?

Comment: If I were you, and I had the option, I'd simply add a `display_name` column to the roles table.

Comment: @jvillian - thanks  - good idea.

Answer (score 0):

create a class level variable like:

```
class MyClass 

   ROLES = [
      ['Guest - Trial Account' ,'guest' ],
      ['Administrator' , 'admin'],
      ['Representative' , 'representative']
   ]

end
```

Then access them on the view:

```
<%= select_tag 'roles', MyClass::ROLES %>
```

More Info : [Here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper)

Comment: but does that interfere with the roles I create with by CRUD setup? I made 'guest' as a role. I want to keep that functionality working, but for the purpose of this list I want to display it differently. Can I use your suggestion without interfering with the setup in the db?

Comment: No its not interfering with the roles on CRUD setup. Let's say you've added a new Role in the db, then you have to manually add that role on that class variable.

Comment: I tried this suggestion, but I get an error that says: undefined method `(Role::ROLES)' for #<Role:0x007fe4a1dedfb8>

Comment: <%= select_tag "roles", options_from_collection_for_select(@roles, "id", "(Role::ROLES)"), :multiple => true, :class => 'chosen-select form-control' %>

Comment: When I remove () from Role::ROLES, I get an error that says:... [after each key value pair you show above]... is not a symbol nor a string

Comment: there must be something wrong with the way the array is written. The error message lists all the pairs in the array and says: is not a symbol nor a string